# How to get exact request (path/params) to be able to redirect back to same place

Tags: java, http, web-applications, spring-mvc

I have spring intrecpetor (implements org.springframework.web.servlet.handler.HandlerInterceptorAdapter), that redirects to login facebbok page, after that I need to redirect to exact same location.

What's the best / fail proof / way to do that

I need to extract request String from HttpServletRequest and put in in the after login redeirect back URL

I'm not shure if

```
WEB_ROOT + request.getContextPath() + "?" + request.getQueryString()
```

is the right solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try the following:

```
public static String getUrl(HttpServletRequest req) {
String reqUrl = req.getRequestURL().toString();
String queryString = req.getQueryString();
if (queryString != null) {
    reqUrl += "?"+queryString;
}
return reqUrl;
```

}

Answer (score 0):

```
public static String getUrl(HttpServletRequest req) { 
    String reqUrl = req.getRequestURL().toString(); 
    String queryString = req.getQueryString(); 

    if (queryString != null) {     
        reqUrl += "?"+queryString; 
    } 

    return reqUrl; 
}
```